# Add Material design css to collection_select options

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, material-design

Hi I am using material design with rails. In particular I am using the select (which can be found [here](http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/)) on a collection_select.

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fullwidth">
   <%= f.label :client, class: 'mdl-textfield__label' %>
   <%= f.collection_select :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Choose a Client" }, { class: 'mdl-textfield__input' } %>
</div>
```

It looks great. until I select the dropdown. Which is I am not styling in my above code. Essentially I need to add the class="mdl-menu__item" to the options.

Quoting [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select),

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
```

would render

```
<select name="post[author_id]" id="post_author_id">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">D. Heinemeier Hansson</option>
  <option value="2">D. Thomas</option>
  <option value="3">M. Clark</option>
</select>
```

so how do I add a css class to the collection_select option tag?

Comment: #post_author_id option {

Comment: @widjajayd I understand how to access this via CSS. I want to know how to assign a class to the option tag in rails